# @OneToOne relation - NOT NULL property persisted as NULL without error in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have the following @OneToOne mapping configuration (just relevant parts):

Entity `Trademark`

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "trademark", optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private ReferenceNumber referenceNumber;
```

Entity `ReferenceNumber`

```
@OneToOne(optional = true)
private Trademark trademark;
```

Database: allow `referencenumber.trademark_id` to be null-FK, no reference column in `trademark` table.

I use following code for entity persising:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
                            //private ReferenceNumber ref;
            ref.setError(0);
                            // Trademark trademark;
            trademark.setReferenceNumber(ref);
            trademark.setService(ref.getService());
            session.save(trademark);
            ref.setTrademark(trademark);
            session.update(ref);
            tx.commit();
            log.debug("Inserted row id={}", trademark.getId());
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            log.error("Error during attempt to persist new trademark", ex);
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();
            log.trace("Db processing time: {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }
```

Now I have noticed that in plenty (but not in all cases) trademark is is persisted into DB but FK to `trademark` in `referencenumber` is not set! I have used such configuration for rather long time (aprox 4 months), and I have never encounter such behaviour before. No error is thrown during runtime. What can be the cause of such behaviour? Not long time ago I have upgraded Hibernate version to `4.2.1.Final`. Possible bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the `TopLink` Implementation `optional=false` does not force a not null foreign key in the generated schema, if you want to apply this constraint, you have to use the `nullable` option in the `@JoinColum` annotation

```
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private ReferenceNumber referenceNumber;
```

Note: If you tried some other JPA Implementation, it could interpret the `optional=false` as a not null constraint